# how to insert this array into my table mysql php?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a problem to insert the following array into my mysql table. I want to insert the array value (abdominal pain,back pain, pain, abd) into my table, but I have no idea to do that on this complicate array. Appreciate.

```html
<?php
$data = array(
  array("table"=>"abdominal pain"),
  array("table"=>"back pain"),
  array("table"=>"pain"),
  array("table"=>"abd")
);

$add_word = $wpdb->query( $wpdb->prepare( 
 "
  INSERT INTO $word_table
  ( word )
  VALUES ( %s )
 ", 
 $data
) );
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize() the value and insert it as a string. Then when you retrieve it, unserialize() it and it will be an array again.

More on http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php